# Get User Agent in my app which doesn't contain a webview

Tags: android, user-agent

I can ask `WebView.getWebSettings().getUserAgentString()` to get the user
agent, but this doesn't work all that well for my app as I need to
instantiate a `WebView` first even though I don't need.

Is there another way to get to the User Agent without using a `WebView.getSetting,` because in my application, I don't need a `webView`?

Help me please

Comment: It's webView.getSettings() where webView is a WebView instance not the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either initialize a Webview and then destroy it, or just hardcode the user agent as a string (and replace at run-time language etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can see how it's determined by looking at the source

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/webkit/WebSettings.java&q=getCurrentUserAgent&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=370

According to the documentation, you can't get a WebSettings object without a WebView.

Do you need it to be exactly the one that the phone would send?  If not, just pick up a standard Android User Agent (not build/version specific)

Comment: Is there any way to find the "web_user_agent" resource string from Android used to format the output? I have searched and can't find it.

Comment: Found it: <string name="web_user_agent"><xliff:g id="x">Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android %s)
        AppleWebKit/525.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Mobile Safari/523.12.2</xliff:g></string>

Comment: Unfortunately, the string has a number of specifics for the Android/WebKit version, making it difficult for us to construct a UserAgent equal to the WebView in our app, one across multiple Android versions...

Answer (score 1):

The information of user agent is obtained from the HTTP headers, which depends on what browser is used to initiate the WebView object. Therefore, it doesn't make sense if you only want to get the user agent string without creating a WebView.

A better way might be create a WebView and set its visibility to GONE. After getting the user agent string, destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

From android Source code.

```
public static String getDefaultUserAgent() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(64);
    result.append("Dalvik/");
    result.append(System.getProperty("java.vm.version")); // such as 1.1.0
    result.append(" (Linux; U; Android ");

    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // "1.0" or "3.4b5"
    result.append(version.length() > 0 ? version : "1.0");

    // add the model for the release build
    if ("REL".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME)) {
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.length() > 0) {
            result.append("; ");
            result.append(model);
        }
    }
    String id = Build.ID; // "MASTER" or "M4-rc20"
    if (id.length() > 0) {
        result.append(" Build/");
        result.append(id);
    }
    result.append(")");
    return result.toString();
}
```